# finding directories and files

Tags: find

I understand that I can find directories with a specific pattern using:

find . -type d -name "tmp_*"

I understand that I can find files with a directory using:

find . -type f -name "tmp.conf"

How would I list all directories starting with tmp_ containing a file called tmp.conf and list the path to that file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
find . -path '*/tmp_*/tmp.conf'
```

or

```
find . -regex '.*/tmp_[^/]*/tmp\.conf'
```

The difference is that the first (which uses ordinary shell wildcards) will match things like `./dir/tmp_foo/subdir/tmp.conf` because `/` is not treated specially by `*`. The second (which uses a regular expression) excludes intervening `/` characters explicitly.

If you want the path to the containing directory only (without the `tmp.conf` basename, you can use the `find` command's `-printf` with the `%h` specifier:

```
find . -path '*/tmp_*/tmp.conf' -printf '%h\n'
```

Alternatively you could do something like

```
find . -type d -name 'tmp_*' -execdir test -e {}/tmp.conf \; -print
```

or

```
find . -type d -name 'tmp_*' -exec sh -c '
  for f do [ -e "$f/tmp.conf" ] && echo "$f"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

- 

Comment: I think I did manage to figure this out.  I did the following:

find ./tmp_* -type f -name "tmp.conf" | sort -f

Comment: @JasonH if you're only interested in a set of top-level directories, then you don't need `find` at all - you could just use `echo tmp_*/tmp.conf` or `printf '%s\n' tmp_*/tmp.conf` (you'd probably want to set `shopt -s nullglob` first).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to Rome. I probably would search specifically for files named `tmp.conf` files and have the full path printed for each occurrence, as in

```
find . -type f -name 'tmp.conf' -exec readlink -f {} \;
```